# CSS width issues:

Tags: css

The way I have my page set up, I have one div centered on the page taking up like 70% of the page (width: 70%), and in that div, I have a banner with text (in a p element) and a table.  This banner is supposed to be the same width as the table, and when I set the width, I had the banner and table set up with their width at 100% (of the container div).  When I shrink the browser horizontally, the table stays the same size, but the banner shrinks to the left, looking really ugly.  And if I smoosh the browser so it's thinner than the biggest word in the text, the text goes right off the banner!  How the duck to I fix something like this?  (Note: The last sentence referred to a tasty aquatic bird, not profanity.  It is not a typo.)

Comment: Spend more time asking your questions, and we'll spend more time answering them.

Comment: ??  I thought I explained my question pretty well.

Comment: welcome to SO, please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). It helps if you add some code so we may see what you're working on. Better yet if you add an image of what you want it to look like.

Comment: go to [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) and set up your scenario so we can work on it. also, use paragraphs

Comment: Please provide us a live example.

Answer (score 0):

For the table issue give the width in percentage

```
 <table width="100%">
```

Give word property , so that the text will break when you shirk.

```
 word-wrap: break-word;
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here (FireFox):

http://jsfiddle.net/W9e2A/1/

The `table` will shrink to the size of its contents at which point it will stop shrinking. That will cause the banner to continue to shrink, and it will make the `table` look ugly (text will flow out).

If you set the `min-width` of your containing `div` to the smallest width of the `table`, it should fix your issue.

As a side-note, if you are using a `table` for something other than tablature data (e.g. layout), you should consider using `div`'s/`span`'s instead.